# Request with params, processing and rendering SPA - architectural approach

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, architecture, single-page-application

I was not sure how to name the question but here is what I need to do and I'm looking for some advice how to handle it architecture-wise. I'm Java / Kotlin developer very familiar with Spring Boot and very basic knowledge of front end as a whole - just so you know my origin.
Here is the flow of my new application:

1. user retrieves a generated link with lots of params that he can click in his browser
2. when he clicks on that link I want to retrieve those params in backend, run some longish external API calls & calculations (up to 10 seconds) and then return results one by one (some websocket or server sent events) and present them in SPA application (preferably React) with results nicely presented so he can pick one of the options I calculated, fill out some form and pay for it.

Maybe I'm confused - I've worked with many front end developers but I never thought how to actually "start" a SPA when someone clicks on some URL with params and then handle all those passed params via backend.

Is what I just wrote doable with React rendered on client side and Spring Boot as the backend? Or do I have to use React server side rendered because I have this static URL with params?
Could someone clarify how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when a SPA is hosted on a domain, the webserver will be configured to redirect all requests on all paths to the root url. So it doesn't matter what path on your domain the user is trying to access, the SPA will still get loaded.

Then in your React SPA you inspect window.location to find the path and params in the url. You then call the backend (most likely on another domain) sending it the params via a web request. It then sends back a response with a random key, and continues to start the time consuming process in the background. When results come in, they are persisted globally in a dictionary against the random key (could be to a database, could be held in memory if you only are going to need one back-end server). Then on another API endpoint, the React front end can poll with the random key and get the current status of the processing, displaying it to the user.